# Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UILabel'

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, viewcontroller

I am trying to pass data from tableview to another page (view controller) but problem is i am getting an error from tableview. Below is the code and i have marked the error where i am getting.

> P1ViewController.Swift

```
class P1ViewController: ViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var name=["Table1","Table2"]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return name.count
    } 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text=name[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    } 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let detail=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
        detail.lblName=name[indexPath.row] //This is the error i am getting "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UILabel'"
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detail, animated: true)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

> DetailViewController.Swift

```
class DetailViewController: ViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    var name:String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lblName.text=name
    }
}
```

Comment: `detail.lblName.text = name[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you would have to write

```
detail.lblName.text = name[indexPath.row]
```

but this will cause a crash. Assign the value to the `name` property

```
detail.name = name[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: the error has gone but after running the code from this same line `detail.lblName.text = name[indexPath.row]` getting a fatal error "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Yes, as I said ***this will cause a crash***. The outlet is not connected yet right after instantiating the controller.

Comment: but i connected the outlet.

Comment: You did, but the outlet doesn't *exist* until the view has been loaded. That's why declaring a property and assigning the value to the label in `viewDidLoad` is the correct way.